# Craft CMS Project Config file override

Tags: craft3, plugins, projectconfig, project.yaml

Hi I am using Craft CMS with the project config file to keep various environments in sync. This generally works fine but I have run into an issue with plugin settings.

I am using the Contact Forms Extension and want to use the reCaptcha on my production site but I want it disabled locally. If I enable it on my production site, it gets disabled every time I deploy as I have it disabled locally.

Is there anyway I can create a plugin settings config to override the project config file?

Comment: Yeh I am finding it a common thing to have plugins locally that are really personal, convenience plugins (eg verbb/cp-nav) - annoying that it isn't easy to stop project config changes from these types of plugins wanting to always propagate to shared repos/deployment servers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this plugin, but could probably do this in your template where the plugin is called:

```
// Get the environment
{% set env = getenv('ENVIRONMENT') %}

// If anything but dev, then load the plugin
{% if env != 'dev' %}
    {% include ['_recaptcha/frontend'] %} 
{% endif %}
```

You can also get the environment from the config:

`{% set env = craft.app.config.env %}`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I know I can remove this from the front end of the website. My question was more related to the plugin settings. i.e there is an option to save responses to the database - if I wanted this on in production but off in local. The Contact Form plugin allows you to have a config file that can have different settings per env

Comment: Gotcha. If the plugin has override-able settings then you should be able to do this in the same way as the contact form plugin.